# How can I update several text values inside an SVG Group?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG element that is composed of a shape and text. This element is replicated several times inside the SVG file and I wanted to take advantage of the symbol and use tags.

But I need to be able to pass values to update the text nodes inside the symbol as each symbol will have it's own value.

**Is there a way to do this without Javascript?**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  <defs>
    <g id="Initials">
      <circle id="bgColor" cx="200" cy="200" r="80" class="cls-9"/>
      <text id="label" fill="white" font-size="50" transform="translate(170, 220)">
      10
      </text>
    </g>
   </defs>
   
   <use href="#Initials" />
   
   <use href="#Initials" x="200" y="0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't using JavaScript be appropriate?

Comment: If there is a way to do this without using Javascript that would be optimal mainly because of resources consumption and performance for a mobile device.

Comment: I'm not sure replacing some contents of a few elements with JS is going to degrade performance - why not try to implement it and optimize if it's needed? Without further information I don't think what you are asking is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @chazsolo. In the example above I only added two elements.In reality the SVG file has over 200 values to update. From my tests running the database query, querying the DOM to match each element with the one from the database and updating the values with Javascript takes too long and fails approval tests for client Quality team.

I know that SVG 2.0 allows for parameters but required embedded image but this is not a valid option since legacy code includes javascript interactions that require inline SVG code to work.

Thus this post as a request for help